# JQuery UI named callback

Tags: javascript, jquery-ui

Why doesn't it work if you use a named function when setting up a slider ?

This works:

```
$( "#slider" ).slider({ 
    change: function (event, ui) { 
        sliderCb (event,ui) 
    } 
});
```

Using this does not...

```
$( "#slider" ).slider({
    change: sliderCb (event, ui)
});
```

I guess you are meant to follow the examples but I'd be interested to know why this doesn't work, is it something to do with the context of the function call/ definition ? How could you make this work with out using an anonymous function or am I barking up the wrong tree ?

Simon

Comment: Shouldn't you use `$( "#slider" ).slider({change: sliderCb});`, the syntax posted is not correct

Answer (score 1):

The first example is assigning an anonymous function declaration to the change property. The second example is **executing** a named function and assigning the return value to the change property.

You can assign named functions fine, you just have the syntax a little off:

```
var sliderCb = function (event, ui) {
    ...
};

$( "#slider" ).slider({change: sliderCb });
```

Note that `sliderCb` is not technically a named function in this example, but that's another question...

Comment: OK I guess that f() in an object literal will call the function. Cheers :-) I was totally on the wrong path ! It works...

Comment: @SimonParker correct, without the `function` keyword to make it a declaration, the interpreter will think you're executing a function rather than declaring the parameters to accept.